# How to define shape for Button in Jetpack compose when using Material design 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material3

I am using Material design 3 with Jetpack compose.

By default the Shape for Button has a corner radius of type full which is 20dp. As per the documentation.
https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/overview

If I look at the shape documentation, I can see following shapes in token section
[image]

However when I provide the Shapes object to the Theme for the app. I don't have an option to customise Full Shape.

Here is my code

```kotlin
Shapes(
    extraSmall = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    small = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    medium = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
    large = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    extraLarge = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
)
```

What I am trying to achieve:

1. I don't want to specify shape explicitly to the each button or create a composable for button and then reuse it everywhere.

I want to apply it once and not need to specify it explicitly as other components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, M3 `FilledButton`'s container shape is by default `ShapeKeyTokens.CornerFull`, as you can see in [`FilledButtonTokens`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/43ec6e258f05a132dcf3f2d0288ea736067a0e1c:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/tokens/FilledButtonTokens.kt;l=27). This token is then converted to `Shape` in [`Shapes.fromToken`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/43ec6e258f05a132dcf3f2d0288ea736067a0e1c:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Shapes.kt;l=157) function:

```
internal fun Shapes.fromToken(value: ShapeKeyTokens): Shape {
    return when (value) {
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerExtraLarge -> extraLarge
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerExtraLargeTop -> extraLarge.top()
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerExtraSmall -> extraSmall
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerExtraSmallTop -> extraSmall.top()
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerFull -> CircleShape
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerLarge -> large
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerLargeEnd -> large.end()
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerLargeTop -> large.top()
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerMedium -> medium
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerNone -> RectangleShape
        ShapeKeyTokens.CornerSmall -> small
    }
}
```

As you can see, `ShapeKeyTokens.CornerFull`, unlike most others, isn't converted to some `Shape` from the theme, but simply to `CircleShape`. This means that it's not possible to do what you want. You will either have to pass your shape to each button or create custom button composable.